# Final installation folder debugging

Tags: installation, environment

When I install my finished product it runs fine until the very last action is done (a button that 'saves' the job).

The program pops this error up:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the app will ignor this error and attempt to continue. If you click quit, the app will close.
>
> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ATR\Save A Job\obj\Release\42\ATR\BackupProgram\Backup.xml

For some reason, the program is looking for the `backup.xml` file in the wrong place. (and seemingly added folders)

The way I'm calling the `backup.xml` file in the program is by:

```
(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFile sX86 & "\ATR\Save A Job\Backup.xml")
```

Which, could be the wrong way, but it makes sense to me.
I would assume that the full path to the file location would be as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATR\Save A Job\backup.xml
```

However, it is looking for it in the wrong place (obvious from the error)

Anyone know why?

Comment: This question sounds awefully localized to your application. How do you handle the path to `backup.xml` in your application? This might be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed guys. It was the permissions to the installation folder. My user was set to "read/write only"...once i switched it to Full Control, everything worked fine